# Escaping "\n" new line in list comprehension vs for loop in Python

Tags: python, newline, stdout, list-comprehension

### Escaping "\n" new line in list comprehension in Python

**for loop**

```
string_grid = ''
for i in self.board:
    string_grid += "\n" + str(i)
return string_grid
```

Returns:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But how come the **list comprehension**:

```
return str(["\n" + str(col) for col in self.board])
```

returns this:

```
['\n[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '\n[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '\n[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '\n[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', '\n[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]']
```

I have been trying to make it work for a long time but no matter what I do, the new-line is not being escaped in the stdout.

Comment: You're seeing the difference between printing a string `s` and printing its *representation* `repr(s)` when converting a list of strings to a single string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first example, you create a string, in the second a list.

You have to join the list to a string:

```
return ''.join("\n{0}".format(col) for col in self.board)
```

Answer (score 6):

This might help you:

```
board = [[0] * 5] * 5       # Produce an empty board
print board                 # Display the board as a list of lists

print("\n".join([str(row) for row in board]))
```

For each row, convert the list of board numbers into a textual representation. Use the `join` function to join each row in the resulting list with a newline. Giving the following output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Replace `print()` with `return`